# programmatically Copy on Cursor position

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to copy the item/text that my cursor is hovering programmatically.

I've tried to simulate the control+c command which it does but doesn't actually copy the item.

```
var copiedItem = keyBoard.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_C);

Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text)
```

It executes the `ctrl+c` button simulation but doesn't copy the item.

Comment: Unless the thing you want to copy is actually selected, I don't imagine it will copy.

Comment: Its an item that you only need to hover over, ctrl+c and then you get a string to your clipboard. Works if I do it manually without actually selecting the item but just hover over it.

Comment: How do you find out you simulated the ctrl+c correctly, if it doesn't do anything ?
Instead of sending a ctrl+c, take the text of the item and put it on the clipboard.
This would also work on things like a label.
An "item" is not a defined word in Windows. Probably you mean a control.
Each control has a text property that could be copied to the clipboard (by you - not by ctrl+c).

Comment: Ctrl+C will be delivered to the window control that has the focus.  The odds that this is also the window that you hover are too low.  Don't use the clipboard at all, obtain the text directly.  Half of the code you need [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/obtain-text-attributes-using-ui-automation).